# RangeSliderView not working in MvxAndroidTargetBinding

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

i implement RangeSliderView binding in MvxAndroidTargetBinding, but it not working
this my code:

```
public class RangeSliderLeftValueBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private readonly RangeSliderView rangeSliderView;

    public RangeSliderLeftValueBinding(RangeSliderView rangeSliderView)
        : base(rangeSliderView)
    {
        this.rangeSliderView = rangeSliderView;
    }


    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(float); }
    }

    public override void SubscribeToEvents()
    {
        rangeSliderView.LeftValueChanged += RangeSliderViewOnLeftValueChanged;
    }

    private void RangeSliderViewOnLeftValueChanged(float value)
    {
        FireValueChanged(value);
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
    }
}
```

this code in setup:

```
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<RangeSliderView>("ProgressLeft", view => new RangeSliderLeftValueBinding(view));
```

code in file xaml:

```
local:MvxBind="ProgressLeft abc, Mode=TwoWay"
```

Please help me !!!
Thanks.

Comment: Mate, rather than just saying *it is not working*, please add more information like what is expected to happen, what is not happening, any errors that you get etc :)

Comment: its message is: MvxBind:Error: 66,58 View type not found - RangeSliderView
[ MvxBind:Error: 66,58 View type not found - RangeSliderView
10-17 11:36:20.276 I/mono-stdout(31653): MvxBind:Error: 66,58 View type not found - RangeSliderView
An unhandled exception occured.

Comment: Can can you include more axml? Plus what is a RangeSliderView?